# ARKit use Lidar mesh to smooth estimated planes

Tags: arkit, mesh, plane, lidar

I'm trying to use ARKit's mesh scene reconstruction (with lidar) data to improve detected plane/geometry detection.

Right now, when pointing to a surface, ARKit gives me a very rough rectangle (far from actual surface's dimension). It happens almost instantly, but still far from the actual shape.

I'm trying to use this plane info, hit detection, and mesh data, to actually draw a smoothed rectangle around the detected surface. I don't expect full code, but rather just some hints of what to do.

Note: I'm using SceneKit (not RealityKit).

This is what I have so far for visualization:

[image: Mesh visualizaiton]
[image: Plane visualization]

Basically, I want the blue rectangle to better adjust to the real world shape by using the already available mesh data.

Comment: Did you figure it out? @Cristiano Coelho

Comment: Nope, the above implementation worked good enough eventually.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using plane extents, use anchor.geometry